# How to manually upgrade docker version on a docker-machine?

Tags: docker

`docker-machine` provides an `upgrade` command, however it only upgrades to the latest stable version

I want to install 1.10RC2 on my docker machines and I am uncertain the steps to do this

**UPDATE**

On the [docker releases page](https://github.com/docker/docker/releases) it shows this command:
`curl -fsSL https://test.docker.com/ | sh`

I thought I'd try that out. I ssh'd in via `docker-machine ssh swarm-master` and ran it.

It looked promising... running it appears to be an install/upgrade script, it did a bunch of stuff. Afterwards:

```
root@swarm-master:~# docker version
Client:
 Version:      1.10.0-rc2
 API version:  1.22
 Go version:   go1.5.3
 Git commit:   c1cdc6e
 Built:        Wed Jan 27 22:14:06 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?
```

Seems to have upgraded, but daemon not running.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/articles/systemd/  shows a couple of ways.  I tried:

```
$ sudo systemctl start docker
```

and

```
$ sudo service docker start
```

In both cases the command returns without output but hasn't seemed to have done anything, the daemon is still not running.

My host is Debian 8.

I can do `docker daemon` and it runs in foreground... doing so for the first time it went through and [migrated all my images](https://github.com/docker/docker/wiki/Engine-v1.10.0-content-addressability-migration)... seems to work fine but

So my question is now - how to properly (as in: same way that docker-machine would do it) run the daemon?

Answer (score 3):

So, I found a way:

```
$ docker-machine ssh swarm-master
swarm-master# curl -fsSL https://test.docker.com/ | sh
swarm-master# docker daemon
```

Wait for the daemon to update all the images to 1.10 format and then leave it running.

Meanwhile in another shell:

```
$ docker-machine regenerate-certs swarm-master
```

(I don't know why we have to do this, but the last restart fails without it)
The command should complete, albeit with the following warning:

```
Copying certs to the local machine directory...
Copying certs to the remote machine...
Setting Docker configuration on the remote daemon...
Unable to verify the Docker daemon is listening: Maximum number of retries (10) exceeded
```

Then:

```
$ docker-machine restart swarm-master
$ eval $(docker-machine env --swarm swarm-master)
$ docker-machine ls
```

At this point you should see the master upgraded and running:

```
NAME           ACTIVE      DRIVER         STATE     URL                       SWARM                   DOCKER        ERRORS
swarm-master   * (swarm)   digitalocean   Running   tcp://123.45.67.89:2376   swarm-master (master)   v1.10.0-rc2
```

Repeat the same steps (minus the `eval` `env`) for each machine in the swarm.

Unfortunately there is still a problem:

```
NAME           ACTIVE      DRIVER         STATE     URL                        SWARM                   DOCKER        ERRORS
swarm-1        -           digitalocean   Running   tcp://123.45.67.98:2376    swarm-master            v1.10.0-rc2
swarm-master   * (swarm)   digitalocean   Running   tcp://123.45.67.89:2376    swarm-master (master)   v1.10.0-rc2
```

Looks good yeah?

But:

```
$ docker info
Containers: 7
Images: 13
Role: primary
Strategy: spread
Filters: health, port, dependency, affinity, constraint
Nodes: 1
 swarm-master: 123.45.67.89:2376
  └ Status: Healthy
  └ Containers: 7
  └ Reserved CPUs: 0 / 1
  └ Reserved Memory: 0 B / 1.026 GiB
  └ Labels: executiondriver=native-0.2, kernelversion=3.16.0-4-amd64, operatingsystem=Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie), provider=digitalocean, storagedriver=aufs
CPUs: 1
Total Memory: 1.026 GiB
Name: 0dc444daa840
```

Only one node recognised as part of the swarm :(

To fix this, go in to the missing swarm node:

```
$ docker-machine ssh swarm-1
swarm-1# docker run -d swarm join --addr=<node ip>:2376 consul://<consul ip>:8500
```

`docker info` should now show both nodes are in the swarm.

Answer (score 0):

Surprised this has not been properly answered yet, and perhaps things changed but this is very easy.  I just ran this test on a swarm with a master and two members.

Before:

```
C:\> docker version
Client:
 Version:      17.06.0-ce
 API version:  1.29 (downgraded from 1.30)
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   02c1d87
 Built:        Fri Jun 23 21:30:30 2017
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.05.0-ce
 API version:  1.29 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   89658be
 Built:        Thu May  4 21:43:09 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
```

Here are the commands in order:

```
C:\> docker-machine upgrade default

Waiting for SSH to be available...
Detecting the provisioner...
Upgrading docker...
Stopping machine to do the upgrade...
Upgrading machine "default"...
Copying I:\Docker\cache\boot2docker.iso to I:\Docker\machines\default\boot2docker.iso...
Starting machine back up...
Restarting docker...


C:\> docker-machine upgrade swarmnode02

Waiting for SSH to be available...
Detecting the provisioner...
Upgrading docker...
Stopping machine to do the upgrade...
Upgrading machine "swarmnode02"...
Copying I:\Docker\cache\boot2docker.iso to I:\Docker\machines\swarmnode02\boot2docker.iso...
Starting machine back up...
Restarting docker...


C:\> docker-machine upgrade swarmnode03

 Waiting for SSH to be available...
Detecting the provisioner...
Upgrading docker...
Stopping machine to do the upgrade...
Upgrading machine "swarmnode03"...
Copying I:\Docker\cache\boot2docker.iso to I:\Docker\machines\swarmnode03\boot2docker.iso...
Starting machine back up...
Restarting docker...
```

After:

```
C:\> docker version
Client:
 Version:      17.06.0-ce
 API version:  1.30
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   02c1d87
 Built:        Fri Jun 23 21:30:30 2017
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.06.1-ce
 API version:  1.30 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   874a737
 Built:        Thu Aug 17 22:54:55 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false

C:\> docker-machine ls
NAME          ACTIVE   DRIVER              STATE     URL                          SWAR
M   DOCKER        ERRORS
default       *        vmwareworkstation   Running   tcp://192.168.200.132:2376
    v17.06.1-ce
swarmnode02   -        vmwareworkstation   Running   tcp://192.168.200.133:2376
    v17.06.1-ce
swarmnode03   -        vmwareworkstation   Running   tcp://192.168.200.134:2376
    v17.06.1-ce
```

Comment: my question was specifically about upgrading to a non-final version, i.e. at the time it was 1.10RC2... yes the `docker-machine upgrade` command works fine to upgrade to current release version